# Akka reliable proxy with typed actors?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, scala-2.9

I just read about [reliable proxies in akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/reliable-proxy.html), but I couldn't find a way to use them with typed actors. What would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Reliable Proxy Pattern is a way to manage the quality of service when sending from one actor to another. TypedActors are not made for this use case, their use is rather limited as I [previously described](http://letitcrash.com/post/19074284309/when-to-use-typedactors). So the answer is: if you want to explore messaging patterns, use normal (untyped) actors, because only they really model the message passing nature of the actor model.